# Minimize/Maximize all windows command?

Tags: gnome, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “show desktop” from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97219/how-to-show-desktop-from-command-line)

I was wondering if there was a shell command that minimizes/maximizes all windows.

I have heard of `wmctrl -k on`, but the program 'wmctrl' is not a default in Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Super-D will minimize/restore all windows.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-ubuntu-unity-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Why the downvote?  This answer meets your needs and is more efficient than typing out a command

Comment: Well, I know I can use Ctrl+Alt+D or Super+D, but I need the terminal command, I'm a developer and I need to use it in a program.

Comment: i am not convinced peeking to the desktop is same functionality as minimizing, furthermore for info it doesnt seem to work in compiz for example

Answer (score 1):

wmctrl is available in the Universe repository. Run `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` to install it.

I'm not a developer, but if your program needs it, I think you can list it as a dependency when you package the program. This will ensure that wmctrl is installed when your program is installed.