# How to "show desktop" from command line?

Tags: unity, command-line

I want to be able to lower all windows and show the desktop from the command line, not
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a useful command line application called `xdotool` which amongst other stuff,  allows you to send keystrokes.

Thus - to mimic <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or whatever the combination is *you* need), you can use one of the following commands:

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+d
xdotool key ctrl+super+d
xdotool key super+d
```

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: The key combination should not be quoted. Works as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure fossfreedom's answer truly satisfies the requirement to "not use Ctrl+Alt+D"

Thus I recommend to show desktop the command:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

To turn it off use

```
wmctrl -k off
```