# When loggin in after inactivity all windows be in minimized state (show desktop wallpaper)

Tags: 20.04, login, 22.04, minimize

I have my work computer in an open space. Is it possible to configure ubuntu so that when I login after inactivity all windows be in minimized state and the PC shows the desktop?
Ubuntu 20.04 / 22.04

Comment: To login, you have to log out first. If you log out, all Windows will be closed. Then there will be nothing to embarrass you in front of your colleagues. :)

Comment: do you mean if the computer locks itself from inactivity, and you have to unlock it?

Comment: @Esther yes this is exactly what I mean. I thought it was clear from the title

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449013/517866 gives a way of writing as script when the device locks/unlocks. Perhaps you can write a script that minimizes all windows and run it on lock or unlock (which is not the same thing as logging in/out, so you might want to edit your question to clarify that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this in Ubuntu 20.04. It seems to work.

## Required software

You will need the utility `wmctrl` and `gnome-screensaver`. If they are not installed, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> use the following command to install them.

```
sudo apt install wmctrl gnome-screensaver
```

## Edit `.profile`

Find the file `.profile` in your Home folder. This is a hidden file. Open the Files app (AKA Nautilus) and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see all the hidden files.

Add the following line at the end of the file `/home/$USER/.profile`:

```
set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Save the file.

### Log out and log back in

The `.profile` is executed when you login to your computer. Logging out (not locking the computer due to inactivity) and logging in will ensure the changes you made in the `.profile` is used.

## Create the script `/home/$USER/bin/unlock_min`

You may call the script something else or place it in some other folder, but you will need to adjust the next step accordingly. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Minimize all open windows if the screen is locked

source /home/$USER/.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

if (/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -q | /bin/grep "is active");
then
    /usr/bin/wmctrl -k on
fi
```

Save this script as `/home/$USER/bin/unlock_min`, where you can replace `$USER` with your username.

## Create a new cron job

You will have this script run every minute to check if the screen is locked. To do this edit your cron jobs using the `crontab` utility. Use the command:

```
crontab -e
```

When you use this command for the first time it may ask you to select a text editing utility. We will use the default `nano`. You may want to familiarize yourself with it.

Add the following line at the end of crontab file opened by the command above:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /bin/bash /home/$USER/bin/unlock_min > /home/$USER/log.txt 2>&1
```

Note, you may have to change `$USER` to your username. This line will run the command every minute and write the output in the file `/home/$USER/log.txt`. If all goes well the `log.txt` will have a line like:

```
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

If there is no `log.txt` or if it contains something else, then something has gone wrong.

## Try it

Open some sensitive windows on your computer. Select the **Lock** from the System Menu (top right corner of your desktop).

Go get a cup of tea/coffee.

Unlock your computer using your password. All the open windows should be minimized.

## References:

- [Ubuntu 18.04: Gnome lock screen refuse correct password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070774/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-lock-screen-refuse-correct-password)
- [How to "show desktop" from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97219/how-to-show-desktop-from-command-line)

Hope this helps

Comment: works perfect thanks

Comment: @ECII Thanks for the edits. I didn't realize `gnome-screensaver` may not be installed by default.

Comment: fantastic answer. Thank you for being so clear with the instructions.