# How to restore all minimized windows?

Tags: unity

I want to know how to restore all windows which I have minimized (using the mouse). I find it annoying to have to browse through my windows manually to restore all of them.

Both GUI-based and command line solutions work for me.

To show that I have searched for answers before posting here:

- I'm not looking to view my Desktop (toggling windows), so I'm not
  duplicating [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63866/minimize-maximize-all-windows-command), nor am I duplicating [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97219/how-to-show-desktop-from-command-line).
- [A solution can be found on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/276110/how-to-restore-all-minimized-windows-in-windows-7/464771), but this is a solution for
  Windows.
- [This link to Unix & Linux includes two possible solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324853/a-quickway-to-unminimize-all-minimized-via-bash-prompt-or-some-installable-utili), but
  both seem to be buggy and/or slow. I hope there is a better way on
  Ubuntu.
- Furthermore, I've searched outside of StackExchange as well, but did not find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, $DESKTOP_SESSION is 'ubuntu'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this post by user55822 on closing all open windows](https://askubuntu.com/a/166686/994965), I found the following solution:

```
WIN_IDs=$(wmctrl -l | awk '$3 != "N/A" {print $1}')
for i in $WIN_IDs; do wmctrl -ia "$i"; done
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, as it does not raise warning messages.

Answer (score 4):

There's a package called xdotools which can do this. The command to be used is;

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name '.*' windowactivate %@
```

You can add this to a shortcut and place it on the toolbar so a single click opens everything.

Comment: Yes, this works! But I get an error message as well: `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)`.

Comment: Yes sorry it did error for me, but I figured if I really wanted to I'd script something to catch and dispose of the error messages, sloppy I know but it's a way around the initial question.